# Button in one activity to do the same as button in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android. In my application, in ActivityOne I want to allow the user to take a picture using a button. The picture is then stored in the gallery and displayed in an ImageView in ActivityTwo.
My question is: How can I add a button to ActivityTwo that allows the user to retake the picture if they don't like it when displayed in the ImageView. Basically, the button will do the same as the one in ActivityTwo. Do I need to write the same code for the button?
I have tried to create a separate that implements View.OnClickListener, add the functionality in the onClick method, and in each activity create an instance of that class attached to the button:

```
onClick(View v) { 
int id = v.getId();
if (id == R.id.myButton) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
myfile = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
v.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
   }
}
```

However, this causes errors as the class is not an activity.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you downvote instead of guiding? I am new to Android!!

Comment: BTW I'm not the down voter. How about handling this logic in single activity ? What is stopping you from that ?

Comment: basically YES, you should duplicate the login in ActivityTwo, but why should you? I'd use only the first activity

Answer (score 0):

You can write the same logic for this second button, but as Naveen mentioned it would be easier to put the button on the first activity, leading to the camera. When the user takes a picture just add an imageview to the layout above the button using linearlayout on the first activity. Then the picture is displayed and the user has the option to retake it.

Comment: I need two activities as I want the first one just for a single button. The second activity will do other things.

Comment: Then you'll have to use the same logic for the button on the second activity

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to let the user take the picture in the activity where it is needed. But if there is a need for you to use it in multiple places, you should extract the code triggered by the button in the first activity(The code that takes the picture) into a separate class. then you can call it from anywhere when needed.

Comment: Thanks. But that separate class, doesn't it have to be another activity? Because I will be using  startActivityForResult() and other methods...

Comment: Just a regular Java class will do

Comment: When I try to use startActivityForResult() in a regular class, it gives me an error Cannot resolve method.

Comment: Every startAcrivity needs a context. You should pass context as a parameter to your method and use it to start the activity.

``` public static void myMethod(Context context) {
     .............
     context.startActivityForResult(...);
}
```

Comment: That's the code in the separate class: public void `onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();


        if (id == R.id.myButton)

        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
           v.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

    }`

Answer (score 0):

@Subzero-273k Follow this.

1. In your activity make two different layouts. One, which shows your first button, remember to hide the other layout by setting the visibility.
2. Once user clicked the button1 which calls someOnClick(), hide first layout and enable another layout, which shows you the imageView and button2, onclick of button2 still calls your old function someOnClick().

How about this? As you dint mention what else you are doing in two different activities, I assume you just show activity one for single button.

Comment: ActivityTwo is more complicated: it'll have several TextViews, ImageViews, buttons, etc. I'm wondering if making that visible/invisible is a good practice?

Comment: I gave this solution because, As your First Activity layout just contains a button.

Comment: That's correct, it contains only a button. But I want the same button to appear in Activity2 based on a condition from the server.The picture will be displayed in the ImageView and sent to the server. If the picture isn't as supposed to be, the server will send a message and the button will appear under the ImageView..